# Connecting Elements with a Line

Tags: javascript, css, lines

I am trying to connect the pin elements and the timeline element with horizontal white lines. Does anyone know how to do this using javascript and css? See reference links below.

Thanks in advance.

- Mike

http://mikedemar.com/devresources/timeline/example.png

http://mikedemar.com/devresources/timeline/index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the markers in a container with `overflow: hidden`, and use a pseudo-element to draw the lines:

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
    <li class="handleicon"></li>
    <li class="handleicon"></li>
    <li class="handleicon"></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```css
ul {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 260px;
}

.handleicon {
    position: absolute;
    width: 33px;
    height: 50px;
    background: url(images/handlered.png);
}
.handleicon:before {
    content: '';
    width: 1px;
    height: 400px;
    background: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 50%;
}
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AAPSg/

Comment: Thanks for your help Joseph. Is there any way you can do a fiddle that keeps the hover functionality of the content tabs?

Comment: @Mike - That wouldn't be very different from what I did here. Try incorporating this into your code. It's not that hard.

Comment: I was able to get everything working with the functionality of the tabs. I have one remaining issue to get the white line to go behind the tab when hovering over a pin. Any advice or hint on how to do that would be greatly appreciated. Thanks for your help. 

http://mikedemar.com/devresources/timeline/

- Mike

Comment: @ Joseph Silber http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12390171/hover-issue-with-timeline