# Hover issue with Timeline

Tags: jquery, html, css, hover

Can anyone help me out with this issue? I am working on having the pin image appear infront of the transparent box when rolled over but keeping the line in back of the box. If anyone has any suggestions of how to solve this I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks in advance.

- Mike

http://resources.29kdev.com/timeline/demo.html

here is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<!-- Attach our CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">  
<!-- Attach necessary JS -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>


<title>Timeline</title>  
</head>
<body>

<!-- =======================================

TIMELINE CONTENT 

======================================= -->
<div id ="pagewrap">    
<div id ="wrapper"> 

    <div id="timeline">

        <img src="images/timeline.png">

    </div> <!--end timeline -->

    <ul> <!--begin ul -->

    <div id="pin01" class="handle">
    <div class="handleicon"><img src="images/handle.png"></div>
    <div class="handleinfo">
        <h3>Lorem Ipsum</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed cursus euismod metus, nec mollis tellus porttitor ut. Nam id accumsan ante. Proin varius ultricies sem et tincidunt.</p>
    </div>
</div> 

<div id="pin02"  class="handle">
    <div class="handleicon"><img src="images/handle.png"></div>
    <div class="handleinfo">
        <h3>Lorem Ipsum</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed cursus euismod metus, nec mollis tellus porttitor ut. Nam id accumsan ante. Proin varius ultricies sem et tincidunt.</p>
    </div>
</div>  



<div id="pin03"  class="handle">
    <div class="handleicon"><img src="images/handle.png"></div>
    <div class="handleinfo">
        <h3>Lorem Ipsum</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed cursus euismod metus, nec mollis tellus porttitor ut. Nam id accumsan ante. Proin varius ultricies sem et tincidunt.</p>
    </div>
</div>   


<div id="pin04"  class="handle">
    <div class="handleicon"><img src="images/handle.png"></div>
    <div class="handleinfo">
        <h3>Lorem Ipsum</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed cursus euismod metus, nec mollis tellus porttitor ut. Nam id accumsan ante. Proin varius ultricies sem et tincidunt.</p>                </div>
</div>
<div id="pin05"  class="handle">
    <div class="handlerighticon"><img src="images/handle.png"></div>
    <div class="handleinfo handlerightinfo">
        <h3>Lorem Ipsum</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed cursus euismod metus, nec mollis tellus porttitor ut. Nam id accumsan ante. Proin varius ultricies sem et tincidunt.</p>
    </div>
</div>

</ul> <!--end ul -->

<div id="title">
    <div id="lefttitle">
        <h4>Our Company History</h4>
    </div> <!--end lefttitle-->
    <div id="righttitle">
        <p class="title">Rollover an Event</p>
    </div> <!--end righttitle-->
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div><!--end title -->
```

```
<!--fadeToggle script -->

<script>
$('.handle').on('mouseover', function(){
$(this).css('z-index', '200000000');
});
$('.handle').on('mouseout', function(){
$(this).css('z-index', '100000000');
});

$('.handleicon').on('mouseover', function(){
$(this).css('z-index', '-200000000');
});
$('.handleicon').on('mouseout', function(){
$(this).css('z-index', '-100000000');
});

$('.handlerighticon').on('mouseover', function(){
$(this).css('z-index', '-200000000');
});
$('.handlerighticon').on('mouseout', function(){
$(this).css('z-index', '-100000000');
});

$(".handle").hover(
    function() {
        $(this).addClass("topdiv");
        $(this).children(".handleinfo").fadeIn("fast");
    },
    function() {

        $(this).children(".handleinfo").fadeOut("fast", function() {$(this).removeClass("topdiv");});
    }
);

$(".handleright").hover(
    function() {
        $(this).addClass("topdiv");
        $(this).children(".handlerightinfo").fadeIn("fast");
    },
    function() {

        $(this).children(".handlerightinfo").fadeOut("fast", function() {$(this).removeClass("topdiv");});
    }
);

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#backgroundfade').fadeOut(2000, function(){$('#maincontent').fadeTo(1000,1);});
});
</script>

</body>
```

Comment: Can you add more information to your question? It will be completely useless once the page you linked to is gone.

Comment: Hey @Kevin B, good point. I added the HTML and Javascript in hopes of adding more information and to keep a backup of the code.

Comment: One note, a `ul` element can't contain `div` elements as children.

Comment: Small question, How did you craete your line under that png? I tried to select them but I am out of luck.

Comment: that line is just because of the `handleicon::before {
content: '';
width: 1px;
height: 200px;
background: white; }` ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DEMO http://jsbin.com/welcome/22311/edit

Just change your jQuery

```
<script>
$('.handle').on('mouseover', function(){
$(this).css('z-index', '200000000');
$(this).find(".handleicon img").css({'z-index':'200000000',"position":"relative"});
});
$('.handle').on('mouseout', function(){
$(this).css('z-index', '100000000');
$(this).find(".handleicon img").css({'z-index': "-1","position":"relative"});
});


$('.handlerighticon').on('mouseover', function(){
$(this).css('z-index', '-200000000');
});
$('.handlerighticon').on('mouseout', function(){
$(this).css('z-index', '-100000000');
});

$(".handle").hover(
    function() {
        $(this).addClass("topdiv");
        $(this).children(".handleinfo").fadeIn("fast");
    },
    function() {

        $(this).children(".handleinfo").fadeOut("fast", function() {$(this).removeClass("topdiv");});
    }
);

$(".handleright").hover(
    function() {
        $(this).addClass("topdiv");
        $(this).children(".handlerightinfo").fadeIn("fast");
    },
    function() {

        $(this).children(".handlerightinfo").fadeOut("fast", function() {$(this).removeClass("topdiv");});
    }
);

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#backgroundfade').fadeOut(2000, function(){$('#maincontent').fadeTo(1000,1);});
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your input @Champ I have added your example but it does not seem to effect the functionality of the rollover states. I might be inputting it wrong. Here is the link. 

http://mikedemar.com/stromasys/timeline/index20120912.html

*This is the same widget with the same code just styled differently.

Comment: I have edited my code ( the jQuary part ) try that if it works.. ?

Comment: m sorry just overlooked the script ... now I have tested it on my machine it works ... try it

Comment: Thank you so much for working this out! It worked perfectly.

http://mikedemar.com/stromasys/timeline/index20120912.html

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `z-index` from the picture container (`<div class="handleicon">`). 
Instead of moving it to the back, move the info box (`<div class="handleinfo">`) and the `<img>` itself to the front (the image being above the info box, for example 200 on the image and 100 on the info box). Both will also need `position:relative` so the `z-index` works, of course.
Z-indexes are complicated. 
If I recall correctly, using z-index on a `position:relative` element defines a new layer, and you cannot put anything in between stuff that is put inside that layer. By avoiding the `position:relative` on the container div, you don't define that layer and can move the picture to the front without making the line of the div also appear at the front.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did,
First, put your Image below your handle class in each div.

```
<div id="pin01" class="handle">
    <img src="images/handle.png"></div> 
    <div class="handleicon">
    <div class="handleinfo">
        <h3>Lorem Ipsum</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed cursus euismod metus, nec mollis tellus porttitor ut. Nam id accumsan ante. Proin varius ultricies sem et tincidunt.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

You will need to do it on each div.
Then on your CSS I change the height of your handleicon class to 0px

```
.handleicon {
    width: 32px;
    height: 0px;
    position:relative; 
}
```